# Arch Gnome-Terminal timeout

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome-terminal, locale

I switched my DM from LightDM to GDM and now I cannot launch gnome-terminal. When I try to launch it from another terminal emulator, I get this error message:

`# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached`

I suspect it has something to do with my location, but my lang is set to en_US.UTF-8

```
<~>-> locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
<~>->
```

Comment: I’ve seen GNOME Terminal not starting while `LC_ALL=C` was in effect.  I then switched to using `LC_COLLATE=C` and `LC_NUMERIC=C`, which for my purpose were enough.  If that works for you, too, and brings back GNOME Terminal, I can see about converting this to an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what exactly I did to fix this, but I think it was some combination of:

```
sudo locale-gen --purge
sudo locale-gen
localectl set-locale LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem, and was very frustrated because `set-locale LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` resulted in no changes in locale.

The fix:
Add these lines to **/etc/environment**:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then reboot.  Note that exporting these settings in .bashrc did not work.

Comment: I found later that my .bashrc file had these set to =C, and the environment settings could override this.  So I should have looked there first.

Comment: setting /etc/environment worked for me after rebooting (Ubuntu 21.04)

Can't really see how a novice can deal with things like this after so many years of these "desktops" being out.